# In what file can I set keyboard layout in home?

Tags: linux, gnome

I have some trouble with linux gnome. I need to set a keyboard layout which is supposed to be used only by me. I do not have administrator rights and I am not sure who is administrating the server. The guess is that this can be done by typing in some special preference in some file in the /home directory. I have been trying to do some research on this, I only find some sudo commands or that I should make a change in /etc/... something to which I will have to change layout globally. Further I cannot modify /etc either.

Does anyone know how I can set keyboard layout for only my user?

Comment: Settings > Keyboard > Input sources...

Comment: @don_crissti I did not look exacly like that, but something like that worked. I thought this would only work for root, but it seemed to work. So thumb up or something like that

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `setxkbmap` command with the layout you want as parameter, you can use the `ibus` GUI application (if available), and there's a lot of other programs that help you change the keyboard layout.